# Yocto Project: tf-a dtc version Error in custom board based on stm32mp157

Tags: stm32, yocto

I am learning yocto project. I started with a custom board based on stm32mp157. You can find the board description in this link [custom board link](https://www.emtrion.de/de/products/emsbc-argon-single-board-computer.html) . Vendor has a board support package in dunfell version. But I am doing my project in kirkstone version. I have following build configuration for creating the image:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "2.0.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "emsbc-argon"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "4.0.11"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "kirkstone:fc697fe87412b9b179ae3a68d266ace85bb1fcc6"
meta-oe              
meta-python          = "kirkstone:a82d92c8a6525da01524bf8f4a60bf6b35dcbb3d"
meta-st-stm32mp      = "kirkstone:ca501bd7dbe023682903ceedddaacd940b0898f4"
meta-argon-bsp       = "<unknown>:<unknown>"
```

I have created my own layer (meta-argon-bsp). In that layer I copied some recipes from the vendor's dunfell layer. I changed many syntax in those recipes. I have one recipe named as recipes-bsp. In that recipe I have tf-a and u-boot recipes.
After compiling my custom image I get an error. The error is referring to dtc version is too old, but I have dtc version 1.6.1. The Error is following:

```
 NOTE: Executing Tasks
 ERROR: tf-a-stm32mp-2.2-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
 ERROR: tf-a-stm32mp-2.2-r0 do_compile: ExecutionError('/home/hico/stm32mp1/build- 
 emsbc/tmp/work/emsbc_argon-poky-linux-gnueabi/tf-a-stm32mp/2.2-r0/temp/run.do_compile.15855', 
 1, None, None)
 ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/hico/stm32mp1/build-emsbc/tmp/work/emsbc_argon- 
 poky-linux-gnueabi/tf-a-stm32mp/2.2-r0/temp/log.do_compile.15855
 Log data follows:
 | DEBUG: Executing python function tfaconfig_env
 | DEBUG: Python function tfaconfig_env finished
 | DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
 | NOTE: make -j 8 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- PLAT=stm32mp1 ARCH=aarch32 
 ARM_ARCH_MAJOR=7 AARCH32_SP=sp_min STM32MP_SDMMC=1 STM32MP_EMMC=1 STM32MP_SPI_NOR=1 
 STM32MP_USB_PROGRAMMER=1 DTB_FILE_NAME=stm32mp157c-emsbc-argon.dtb -C 
 /home/hico/stm32mp1/build-emsbc/tmp/work/emsbc_argon-poky-linux-gnueabi/tf-a-stm32mp/2.2- 
 r0/git DTB_FILE_NAME=stm32mp157c-emsbc-argon.dtb BUILD_PLAT=/home/hico/stm32mp1/build- 
 emsbc/tmp/work/emsbc_argon-poky-linux-gnueabi/tf-a-stm32mp/2.2-r0/build/trusted 
 AARCH32_SP=sp_min
 | make: Entering directory '/home/hico/stm32mp1/build-emsbc/tmp/work-shared/emsbc-argon/tfa- 
 source'
 | Including bl32/sp_min/sp_min.mk
 | /bin/sh: 1: printf: v10601+: expected numeric value
 | dtc version too old (v1.6.1+), you need at least version 1.4.4
 | make: *** [plat/st/stm32mp1/platform.mk:251: check_dtc_version] Error 1
 | make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 |   HOSTCC  stm32image.c
 |   HOSTLD  stm32image
 | 
 | Built stm32image successfully
 | 
 | make: Leaving directory '/home/hico/stm32mp1/build-emsbc/tmp/work-shared/emsbc-argon/tfa- 
  source'
 | ERROR: oe_runmake failed
 | WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
 ERROR: Task (/home/hico/stm32mp1/meta-argon-bsp/recipes-bsp/trusted-firmware-fa/tf-a- 
 stm32mp_2.2.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
 NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2845 tasks of which 2838 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

And the log file is following:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function tfaconfig_env
DEBUG: Python function tfaconfig_env finished 
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
NOTE: make -j 8 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- PLAT=stm32mp1 ARCH=aarch32 
ARM_ARCH_MAJOR=7 AARCH32_SP=sp_min STM32MP_SDMMC=1 STM32MP_EMMC=1 STM32MP_SPI_NOR=1 
STM32MP_USB_PROGRAMMER=1 DTB_FILE_NAME=stm32mp157c-emsbc-argon.dtb -C 
/home/hico/stm32mp1/build-emsbc/tmp/work/emsbc_argon-poky-linux-gnueabi/tf-a-stm32mp/2.2- 
r0/git DTB_FILE_NAME=stm32mp157c-emsbc-argon.dtb BUILD_PLAT=/home/hico/stm32mp1/build- 
emsbc/tmp/work/emsbc_argon-poky-linux-gnueabi/tf-a-stm32mp/2.2-r0/build/trusted 
AARCH32_SP=sp_min
make: Entering directory '/home/hico/stm32mp1/build-emsbc/tmp/work-shared/emsbc-argon/tfa- 
source'
Including bl32/sp_min/sp_min.mk
/bin/sh: 1: printf: v10601+: expected numeric value
dtc version too old (v1.6.1+), you need at least version 1.4.4
make: *** [plat/st/stm32mp1/platform.mk:251: check_dtc_version] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
HOSTCC  stm32image.c
HOSTLD  stm32image

Built stm32image successfully

make: Leaving directory '/home/hico/stm32mp1/build-emsbc/tmp/work-shared/emsbc-argon/tfa- 
source'
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

I tried to solve the dtc version error, but still I have the same error. Can anyone help me to solve the error. Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `dtc -v` command? Also, do you happen to have a url for the repo of ATF you are building? The `plat/st/common/common.mk` file could be interesting to see how it looks.

Comment: Version: DTC 1.6.1

you can find the tf-a and u-boot files in this git repo.

https://github.com/emtrion

Comment: In the mainline A-TF there are 2 small commits fixing this problem: [1](https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware/commit/03d20776efc20a04a5191a4f39965079a4d60b3c) and [2](https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware/commit/429f10e3367748abd33b4f6f9ee362c0ba74dd95) (They are the same 1 line fix, but the first was a bit buggy) Patching your version with this change should fix this

Comment: Thanks a lot, I followed your instructions and the tf-a error has been solved. Also I compiled the whole yocto custom image and atlast I don't have any error. I hope I can boot the image successfully. Thanks again.